# Rasterising a TTF font

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, truetype, rasterizing

I'm on the Raspberry Pi with a screen attached.

Rather than using X, I'm writing pixel data directly to the frame buffer. I've been able to draw images and primitive shapes, blend, use double buffering, etc...

Where I'm hitting a problem is drawing text. The screen is just a byte array from this level, so I need a way to take the font, size, text, etc. and convert it into a bitmap (actually, a `bool[]` and `width`/`height` would be preferable as it saves additional read/writes.

I have no idea how to approach this.

Things I've considered so far...

- Using a fixed-width font and an atlas/spritemap. Should work, I can already read images, however monospaced fonts have limited visual appeal. Also means adding more fonts is arduous.
- Using a fixed-width font, an atlas and a mask to indicate where each character is. Would support variable-width fonts, however, scaling would be lossy and it seems like a maintenance nightmare unless I can automate the atlas/mask generation.

Has anyone managed to do anything like this before?

If a library is required, I can live with that but as this is more an exercise in understanding my Pi than it is a serious project, I'd prefer an explanation/tutorial.

Comment: The PIL (pillow) module can rasterize TrueType Fonts, so you could use it to create bitmaps of the font's characters as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [Cairo](https://cairographics.org/) graphics library, either for all your graphics, or as a tool to generate the font atlases. Cairo has extensive support for rendering fonts using TTF fonts, as well as for other useful graphics operations.

At a lower level, you could also use the [Freetype](https://www.freetype.org/) library to load fonts and render characters from them directly. It's more difficult to work with, though.